# PHP Select query duplicates output into table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select content from my database based on user criteria and then display into a table. The user criteria that is received is id, mid and pid.

This is then used in a select query to produce results that are displayed in a table. The results are unfortunately being duplicated, for example, the table displayed is:

[image: DIN LENGTH MATERIAL THREAD SIZE 558 10mm GRADE 4.8- MILD STEEL METRIC 5X10 558 20mm GRADE 4.8- MILD STEEL METRIC 5X20 558 10mm GRADE 4.8- MILD STEEL METRIC 5X10 558 20mm GRADE 4.8- MILD STEEL METRIC 5X20]

When it is supposed to display:

[image: DIN LENGTH MATERIAL THREAD SIZE 558 10mm GRADE 4.8- MILD STEEL METRIC 5X10 558 20mm GRADE 4.8- MILD STEEL METRIC 5X20]

The php code is below:

```
<?php 
    
if ( isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['mid']) && isset($_POST['pid'])) {
$id = ($_POST['id']);
$mid = ($_POST['mid']);
$pid = ($_POST['pid']);
    
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from SetScrews where DID=$id and MID=$mid and PID=$pid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result !== false && $result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  
  
  echo '<table>
  <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center; color:white; background-color:#000000;">DIN</th>
        <th style="text-align:center; color:white; background-color:#000000;">LENGTH</th>
        <th style="text-align:center; color:white; background-color:#000000;">MATERIAL</th>
        <th style="text-align:center; color:white; background-color:#000000;">THREAD</th>
        <th style="text-align:center; color:white; background-color:#000000;">SIZE</th>
    </tr>';
    
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
    echo '<tr>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:black; background-color:#b4c6e7;">' .$row['DIN'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:black; background-color:#b4c6e7;">' .$row['LENGTH'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:black; background-color:#b4c6e7;">' .$row['MATERIAL'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:black; background-color:#b4c6e7;">' .$row['THREAD'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; color:black; background-color:#b4c6e7;">' .$row['SIZE'].'</td>
         </tr>';    

  }

} else {
  echo "0 results";

}

$conn->close();
}


   ?>
```

Comment: From the code you've shown, the only way that could occur is if the sql query returns more rows than you had expected

Comment: Just curious, can you confirm the database itself in fact does not have double records and your code is actually working correctly? If not, place an `echo '@';` a few places, once at a time, to make sure part of your script is not repeating for a reason not shown.

Comment: FYI: Your code is open for [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Thank you, I will review database and code. I will also change code to prevent SQL injections, thanks

Comment: I think there are duplicate records in the database; just verify in your database first. If there are duplicates, you can ignore them by grouping them by DIN and length, which will only return two records. Thanks